# Cancan, allow users to only view or edit their own content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, permissions, cancan

I'm setting up a very basic web application with Rails, I've already got devise set up and working.

My problem as of now is that no matter who I am signed in as I can view and destroy the content of the account I was last signed in on.

I only need 2 types of roles, members, and guests. Members should be only able to view, edit and destroy their own content, and guests should only be able to stare at the register screen.

Can someone help me out? I have cancan installed and have the abilities folder.

I copied some settings from a few other questions on this site and none have worked so far, here is my current users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name , :email # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     ROLES = %w[member guest]


  def is?( requested_role )
    self.role == requested_role.to_s
  end
end
```

and my current abilities

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role == "member"
      can :manage, :user_id => user.id
    elsif user.role == "guest"
      cannot :manage, :all, 
  end
end
```

Comment: We need to see code in order to help you out.

Comment: ok.. i copied a few things from other questions on this site, but none worked for me, here is my users.rb

Answer (score 2):

> in `ability.rb`

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

  # admin
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all

  # member
  elsif user.has_role? :member
    can :manage, User, id: user.id
    cannot :index, User

  # guest
  else
    cannot :manage, User
  end
```

And don't forget to include `load_and_authorize_resource` in the beginning of user controller after `before_action` line. For example, like this

[image]

> Proof: It definitely works

User trying to get details of another user, result 401

[image]

User trying to get his own details, result 200

[image]

User trying to read all users, result 401

[image]

> Why `:manage, User, user_id: user.id` won't work?

Bcoz it searches for `users.user_id` which would definitely be not there

[image]

Comment: etiquette is adding a comment on how the post can be improved, when downvoting

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Looks like your syntax might be a little off:

```
if user.role == "member"
  can :manage, User, :user_id => user.id
elsif user.role == "guest"
  cannot :manage, User, :all
end
```

Make sure to pass in the model (User) as the second attribute to the `can` and  `cannot` methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part?

Comment: unfortunately, no. any user can still view and edit all content from any user

Comment: does not work! as @Youngmathimus told, member can not only view and edit his own, but also that of others!

Comment: It tries to look for `user_id` inside of `user` record.